# theme continuous deployment from bitbucket to windows azure

Tags: themes, git

I need to set up continuous deployment of a wordpress theme controlled via bitbucket to a Windows Azure hosted wordpress install.

One of the sites I run has had a external agency develop a theme that they will be supporting the development of for the foreseeable future.

Is there a set method I should use?

Azure wants to set up source control for the root of the site, but this would include the whole wordpress install, which seems a bit crazy.

How do I got about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all that is required is a .deployment file in the repository

```
[config]
DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = D:\home\site\wwwroot\path\to\theme
```